# Add onclick event to an HMTL element (img) with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a js function which creates an img tag and appends it to a div tag:

```
function createImg() {
    let image = document.createElement("img");
    image.src = "random.png";
    document.querySelector("div").appendChild(image);
```

I want to add to this img an onclick event, so that when I click on it another function will run. How can I do that? I already searched something on stack and found .addEventListener() & .onclick() but both seem to not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the event listener to the image like:

```
image.addEventListener('click', function(){
  // do something
})
```

```js
var x = 0;

function createImg() {
  let image = document.createElement("img");
  image.src = `random${x}.png`;
  image.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(this.src)
  })
  x++;
  document.querySelector("div").appendChild(image);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<button onclick="createImg()">
  button
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add id attribute first

```
  image.id = "imgDemo";
```

Then after appending add the event listener like below:

```
document.getElementById("imgDemo").addEventListener('click', function() {
     //function call here
  }, false);
```